# Issues Mapping EF Multiple of Same Relationship Type

Tags: entity-framework, fluent

I have two POCO Entity classes

```
public class Model
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }


    // Relationships    
    public virtual ICollection<Shoot> PhotoSets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Shoot> FilmSets { get; set; }

}

public class Shoot
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ShootType { get; set; }

    // Relationships
    public long ModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }

}
```

So I only want a single table with multiple types dfined by the ICollection navigation properties on Model.  If I let EF generate by convention it creates Model_dId as an extra property which I want to avoid.  In my Fluent mapping ModelConfiguration class I tried this:

```
this.HasMany(m => m.FilmSets)
    .WithRequired(sh => sh.Model)
    .HasForeignKey(sh => sh.ModelId);

this.HasMany(m => m.PhotoSets)
    .WithRequired(sh => sh.Model)
    .HasForeignKey(sh => sh.ModelId);
```

and get `Additional information: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'PronHunter.Database.Model_FilmSets' was not loaded because the type 'PronHunter.Database.Shoot' is not available.`

I tried from ShootConfiguration defining both paths with:

```
this.HasRequired(sh => sh.Model)
    .WithMany(m => m.PhotoSets)
    .HasForeignKey(sh => sh.ModelId);

this.HasRequired(sh => sh.Model)
    .WithMany(m => m.FilmSets)
    .HasForeignKey(sh => sh.ModelId);
```

which builds a database when querying the first time but it still generates the extra Model_Id column.  In fact I also tried renaming ModelId to ModelaaaId but then I ended up with three columns, ModelaaaId, ModelId and Model_id so EF is ignoring my explicit naming anyway.

So my feeling is it's a many to many scenario but I've tried following some examples but I don't see MapLeftColumn on any intellisense and it isn't a straight many to many scenario anyway.  It's two one to manies I want to define as if I define two inner joins in T-SQL.

Anyone know how I should go about this?

Comment: Mmm, perhaps I need Table Per Hierarchy.  Although I have no fields which are specific to either.  They're both the same shape so it seems overkill to inherit from some base type but have no extra properties

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're all set to use TPH with `ShootType` as your discriminator - derive two new types (e.g. `FilmSet` and `PhotoSet`) from `Shoot` then configure the discriminator `ShootType` as described in [this MSDN article](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).  You would then use these types for the two different collections:

```
public class FilmSet : Shoot {}
public class PhotoSet : Shoot {}

// DbContext model configuraiton
modelBuilder.Entity<Shoot>()  
    .Map<FilmSet>(m => m.Requires("ShootType").HasValue("Film Set"))  
    .Map<PhotoSet>(m => m.Requires("ShootType").HasValue("Photo Set"));

public class Model
{
    public virtual ICollection<FilmSet> FilmSets { get; set; }
    public virtual IColelction<PhotoSet> PhotoSets { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create two unmapped properties to filter a single mapped collection.  You will need to use the single mapped collection for add/remove operations, however:

```
public virtual ICollection<Shoot> Shoots { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<Shoot> PhotoSets { 
    get { return Shoots?.Where( s => s.ShootType == "Photo Set" ); } 
}
public IEnumerable<Shoot> FilmSets { 
    get { return Shoots?.Where( s => s.ShootType == "Film Set" ); } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  GIven my two subtypes are actually identical is TPH the only way to go?

Comment: That's the only time one can use TPH without violating the 3NF!  You could create two unmapped properties that filter a single mapped collection but you must use that single collection for add/removal operations.